# Area under the ROC curve for lo

Tags: predictive-models

What is the acceptable area under the ROC curve in order for a logistic predictive model to be acceptable? If 0.7 acceptable

Comment: Say that you spend half a year on testing 1000 classifiers (and their combinations), neither of them gave AUCROC>07, but your alternative is to recommend the products by coin toss (AUCROC=0.5). So you can choose "unacceptable" (in your words) AUCROC that would higher expected revenue, or businesses as usual -- what would you choose? "Acceptable" is very relative.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question

1. is an AUC 0.7 statistically significant? This will depend on the sample sizes in each group. You can use this online tool to calculate this http://vassarstats.net/roc_comp.html or you should be able to do it in most statistical packages.

   a. better than random chance? For a two group situation the comparator will be assigned an AUC of 0.5.

   b. better than a comparator? if a model exists for making the same decision is your model significantly better than it?
2. is an AUC of 0.7 practically significant? Is AUC of 0.7 good enough for the model to be of practical use? To look at it very crudely with an AUC of 0.7 you expect to be right 2.3 times more often than wrong. This may be a useful increase in your confidence in your knowledge or it may not be depending on the situation and the benefits and risk associated with making a decision.